# Conditional lag function

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

Data based on the dataset from Kaggle [here](https://www.kaggle.com/bigquery/google-analytics-sample) and extracted to R.

Using the following structure:

```
Index   VisitorId           VisitId     Visit# Hit# pagePath
0       000722514342430295  1470093727  1      1    /home
1       000722514342430295  1470093727  1      3    /google+redesign/apparel
2       000722514342430295  1470093727  1      4    /asearch.html
3       000722514342430295  1470093727  1      5    /asearch.html
4       0014659935183303341 1470037282  1      1    /home
5       0015694432801235877 1470043732  1      1    /home
6       0015694432801235877 1470043732  1      2    /google+redesign/electronics
7       0015694432801235877 1470043732  1      3    /google+redesign/apparel/men++s/men++s+t+shirts
8       0015694432801235877 1470043732  1      4    /google+redesign/apparel/kid+s/kid+s+infant
9       0015694432801235877 1470043732  1      5    /google+redesign/apparel/kid+s/kid+s+infant/quickview
```

I'm trying to implement a mutate lag function which will return the previous pagepath for a given visit by a given visitor.

For example, new column `prev_path` would be both visitorid and visitid specific and would lag Hit# by 1 but would return an `<NA>` when not available in the case of Visit 1, Hit 2.

Comment: so the way to do conditional mutates is to do `mutate(ifelse(condition, do this is true, do this if false))`. I'd write the specific code but don't fully understand the condition, could you be more specific pls? Ideally you can write out your expected output dataframe

Comment: So, first of all: What is your question? Did you try to implement this yourself? Which problems occurred when you tried to implement this? Stackoverflow is not a coding service, but a site for help with coding problems. Currently it is not clear from your question (and the phrasing) what exactly you are trying to achieve. Re-read your question and try rephrasing it as a coding problem. Check out [what not to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) which will help you to provide a better question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(VisitorId, VisitId) %>%
  mutate(prev_path = ifelse(lag(`Hit#`) == `Hit#` - 1, lag(pagePath), NA))
```

Comment: This was it exactly. I was going to add the desired state example but you got this perfectly. Can I ask why you changed from the previous version to this version though?

Comment: Excellent. I just simplified the solution by combining the two mutate operations into one. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

We can do a group_by option

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(VisitorId, VisitId) %>%
   mutate(prev_path = case_when(lag(`Hit#`) == `Hit#` -1 ~ lag(pathPath), 
            TRUE ~ NA_integer_))
```